# Error while calling SetsockoptString with IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP in golang

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

I need to call IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP in golang with params. Here's my code

```
s := "239.195.140.6 0.0.0.0 91.203.255.242"
err = syscall.SetsockoptString(socket, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP, s)
```

But it throw invalid argument error
What's the right way to make it?

Comment: To solve this problem I use cgo. Just call syscall in C function with returning socket

Answer (score 1):

[`man 7 ip`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) says `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP` is supposed to take an `ip_mreq_source` structure, but by using `SetsockoptString`, you're giving it a string instead. I don't see a variant of `Setsockopt` that passes the right kind of structure, so it looks like if you want to do this in Go, then you'll have to write some low-level glue code yourself.